# How to print current_user name and Logout button in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I want to display this

```
Current user name - Logout( redirect to home page )
```

This is my current code:

```
echo $current_user->display_name . "\n"; 
echo <a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( home_url() ); ?>" title="Logout">Logout</a>
```

But when i click on a link, i get only "" in address bar. The function is not being recognized.

Thanks

Comment: sorry - this is - <a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( home_url() ); ?>" title="Logout">Logout</a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
echo '<a href='. wp_logout_url( home_url() ) .' title="Logout">Logout</a>';
```

you are mixing php code and echo

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the global variable and initialize it for it to be usable.

Above where you need to call it, add this

```
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
echo $current_user->display_name
```

It will call in the variable and allow access to its data and functions.

Read more about getting use information [HERE](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_currentuserinfo)

For the URL, try this:

```
echo '<a href="'. wp_logout_url(home_url()) .'" title="Logout" />Logout</a>';
```

Comment: This is working, but when i click on <a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( home_url() ); ?>" title="Logout">Logout</a>  - in link bar, i get the function - <?php echo wp_logout_url( home_url() ); ?>, not the home page..

Comment: This is due to you not escaping the php. see amended answer.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the current `username` of logged in admin.

```
global $current_user;
echo $current_user->user_login;
```

[Function Refrence](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_currentuserinfo)